# K-means clustering - with an extra variable

Tags: python, math, scikit-learn, k-means

I'm doing a k-means clustering, with a fixed amount of groups, of several geographical lat/lon points. This basic clustering works just fine.

But i have another variable (one for each point) which i would like the k-means clustering to account for. Is this possible somehow?

The clustering data could look like this:

```
Lat: [1.23, 2.12, 3.65, 4.32, 5.63, 5.43]
Lon: [1.43, 2.43, 3.76, 4.43, 5.25, 1.75]
Extra variable: [20, 20, 10, 10, 10, 10]
```

If i want the above data divided into 2 groups, and the sum of the extra variable for each group cannot exceed the sum of 40, how would i go about this? (If it's possible at all - My understanding of k-means is pretty basic/low-end.)

Comment: can you share code, and what you tried so far, highlighting the error you get?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors. I just cannot figure out which approach/method to use to get the extra variable included in the k-means grouping. Neither by soft limit (taking it into account) or hard limit (with a cut-off at ie. sum of 40).

If needed, this is my kmeans initiating code:
`kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0, init="k-means++").fit(lat_lon_numpy_array)`

Answer (score 2):

It seems that this is no longer a basic clustering application but rather an optimization problem with constraints. In words, you are hoping to accomplish:

> Minimize the total distance (in lat lon) between points grouped into cluster 1 and the points grouped into cluster 2
>
> subject to the constraint that the sum of Extra variable in cluster 1 and in cluster 2 is less than 40 for each cluster.

This is a nonlinear program, so you'd have to use a non-linear optimization tool to solve this.

Alternatively, depending on the size of the data, you could modify k-means clustering such that it continues to shift cluster centroids and reassign data points, but detect when a data reassignment will push a cluster over the limit for the sum of Extra variable. In this case, you could move the centroid of the cluster randomly instead. Keep track of the best set of clusters (some combination of low intracluster distance and high intercluster difference), and after some amount of time, use the best set of clusters obtained by this method.

Comment: Thanks for the input - What non-linear optimization tool would you recommend, or point me in the direction of?

Comment: From what i can read pyOpt will cluster similar data, but so that (from my above example) 20, 20 will be clustered and 10, 10, 10, 10 will be clustered. - Or am i missing something? - What we want is optimally 20, 10, 10 in each of the clusters. (I'm looking at this example [http://www.pyopt.org/examples/examples.autorefine.html])

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that your optimal solution is clusters that have points that are as close to one another as possible (Euclidean distance-wise based on lat and long) that satisfy the hard constraint that the sum of the cluster values ? If this is the case, I'm not sure that there is a clustering package available that solves what you are trying to accomplish out of box. Thus, you'll have to define a custom non-linear program and use a generic non-linear program solving package to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so just add in the extra feature and run it.

```
data = np.asarray([np.asarray(df['Lat']),np.asarray(df['Lon']),np.asarray(df['Extra variable'])])
```

See the link below for more info.

https://www.pythonforfinance.net/2018/02/08/stock-clusters-using-k-means-algorithm-in-python/